# The ceph build instructions do not work. What should I do next?

Tags: build, arm64, ceph, ninja

"ceph" build instructions are here https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/install/build-ceph/
but they do not work. I get

> tjcw@cuttlefisharmserver:~/workspace/ceph_v16.2.6/build$ ninja -j256
>
> ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory
>
> tjcw@cuttlefisharmserver:~/workspace/ceph_v16.2.6/build$

There is a build.ninja file in the directory tree

> tjcw@cuttlefisharmserver:~/workspace/ceph_v16.2.6$ find . -name build.ninja
>
> ./src/seastar/build.ninja
>
> tjcw@cuttlefisharmserver:~/workspace/ceph_v16.2.6$

but that does not seem to be the right place.

What should I do next ? I am new to building ceph, so it could easily be finger trouble. I am trying to build on an ARM64 machine, not x86-64

> tjcw@cuttlefisharmserver:~/workspace/ceph_v16.2.6$ uname -a
>
> Linux cuttlefisharmserver 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:30:45 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
>
> tjcw@cuttlefisharmserver:~/workspace/ceph_v16.2.6$

This is a fully-patched Ubuntu 20.4 machine

Comment: This could easily be finger trouble because this is the first time I have tried to build ceph

Comment: Bug fix for v16.2.6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ceph/ceph_16.2.6-0ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz → patches/ , Ref. https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/impish/ceph ......... Testing : ninja build files appear with the git version https://github.com/ceph/ceph → `./do_cmake.sh` ........ Else: `cd build/ && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo && make`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use 'make' instard of 'ninja'. Ceph is in process of transitioning its build system from make to ninja; the level of Ceph I was trying to build requires 'make'.